# Inertial Reference Frames (Newtonian Mechanics)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I have a hard time understanding Inertial Reference Frames. Is it just scenarios where Newton's laws seem to be violated in the case of non-inertial frames and where Newton's laws are followed in inertial frames?

Comment: This [classic PSSC film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRDOqiqBUQY) from 1960 explains frames of reference.

Comment: That's a pretty good way of putting it. If, in your choice of frame, free bodies keep moving evenly along straight lines, then your frame is an inertial frame, if they are not, then it's not. There are a few catches here, though: first of all it's only true locally (this leads to general relativity) and secondly it's not trivial to determine what a "free body" is.

Answer (score 0):

What really confused me when I was starting the subject was that I haven't found an accurate definition of a reference frame. I think a better concept is that of an inertial coordinate system. Each coordinate system comes with a notion of what a straight line is (this is called an affine connection). An inertial coordinate system in space is one in which a particle which has no net interactions moves along this straight line. In such a formulation Newton's first law actually defines an inertial coordinate system.

One gets a much better picture by thinking on coordinate systems in spacetime, not in space. Using these coordinate systems Newton's first law states that particles move along straight lines (in spacetime) independently of the coordinate system. In particular one defines an inertial coordinate system to be one in which the straight line equation in spacetime becomes a straight line equation on space. This gives a very useful caracterization of inertial coordinate systems in terms of the cristoffel symbols. This approach needs a lot of differential geometry of course.

Comment: I must add that an affine connection is not something that comes with a coordinate system. In the first exposition I gave of Newton's first law it is assumed that there is a definite concept of a straight line. In the second, the law is actually an experimental prescription for a straight line